# Freeradius 2.x to 3.x LDAP configuration with multiple AD trees

Tags: centos, ldap, freeradius

I am trying to migrate an older 2.x server to 3.x due to the LDAPS connectivity requirement for a new AD tree/domain that is being created. I had to upgrade not only Freeradius but the server OS to support newer versions of TLS. I roughly had the configuration I think correct in 2.x, but cannot be 100% certain as authentication to the new AD tree structure was not completely working because of the SSL/TLS incompatibility. I am having a harder time with the new module configuration layout in 3.x.

The current 2.x performs authentication for 2 methods:
 1) LDAP to the existing AD tree using a redundant server setup
 2) SQL/PERL via a custom module.

The new 3.x server I need to perform 3 authentication checks via 2 methods:
 1) LDAP to the existing AD tree using a redundant server setup
 2) LDAPS to the new AD tree (possible redundant server setup)
 3) SQL/PERL via the custom module

I have read that this may require templates for the LDAP configuration, but have not found any examples for that. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so I have part of the multiple AD servers solved, but can't get authe working to the old AD tree yet in 3.x. I have some settings from the 2.x LDAP module configuration that I haven't found the 3.x matching setting for. In 2.x, the configuration had the following settings:
"password_attribute = unicodePwd"
and
"dictionary_mapping = ${raddbdir}/ldpa.attrmap"
Can someone help with either of those?

Answer (score 0):

The config is all in the LDAP module configuration file, `raddb/mods-available/ldap` - the ldap attribute map is in there, too.

To connect to two different LDAP servers, create two instances of the ldap module, e.g. where you have

```
ldap {
  ...
}
```

add another copy of that config with

```
ldap ldap-new {
  ...
}
```

then you can call `ldap` or `ldap-new` as appropriate in the server where needed to query the required LDAP server.

Make sure you create the appropriate symlinks to enable the module, e.g. `raddb/mods-enabled/ldap -> ../mods-available/ldap`.

You can certainly use templates to save duplicating config, but to begin with it's a lot easier to just copy the ldap config file, change the instance name in the new file and then tweak from there. Templates are likely to make things more confusing unless you know what you're doing.